# Issues while accessing spring boot application as Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have a spring boot application with GET and POST methods in a controller 
    and in order to deploy the application as Lambda function "aws-lambda-java-
    core" is added as a dependency in pom.xml and uploaded the jar file to 
    lambda function. When I try to access the API gateway for the get method, it 
    is throwing error as Class not found:

```
 com.Test.TestController(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException")
```

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: This sounds like you don't have the manifest properly defined or included in the build you are uploading to AWS Lambda.   What build tool are you using?

Comment: DDeMartini - I am using Maven to build the application